# Transform multiple non-primitive recursive calls to iterative solution

Tags: c++, parsing, recursion, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a handwritten recursive descent parser as a self exercise. I'd like to see if an iterative approach is possible. Generally speaking, I'd like to know what mindset I should have in order to transform interdependent recursive functions into an iterative solution.

In my current minimal example, I have a list of Tokens (which is simply a type with a lexeme) and they are consumed via recursive descent to build an abstract syntax tree represented by a `unique_ptr` to an expression:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

enum Type { Num, Add, Mul, LParen, RParen };

struct Token {
  Type type;
  std::string lexeme;
};

struct Expr {
  Token token;
};

using AST = std::unique_ptr<Expr>;

struct Literal : public Expr {
  double value;
};

struct Grouping : public Expr {
  AST inner;
};

struct Binary : public Expr {
  AST lhs, rhs;
};

using CIT = std::vector<Token>::const_iterator;

auto expression(CIT& it, CIT end) -> AST;

auto literal(CIT &it, CIT end) -> AST {
  if (it != end and it->type == Type::Num) {
    auto value = std::stod(it->lexeme);
    auto token = *it++;
    return std::make_unique<Literal>(Literal{ token, value });
  }
  else if (it != end and it->type == Type::LParen) {
    auto token = *it++;
    auto ast = std::make_unique<Grouping>(Grouping{ token, expression(it, end) });;
    if (it != end and it->type == Type::RParen)
      return ast;
    else
      throw "Mismatched parenthesis";
  }

  throw "Unable to parse literal";
}

auto multiplication(CIT &it, CIT end) -> AST {
  auto ast = literal(it, end);

  while (it != end and it->type == Type::Mul) {
    auto token = *it++;
    ast = std::make_unique<Binary>(Binary{ token, std::move(ast), literal(it, end) });
  }

  return ast;
}

auto addition(CIT &it, CIT end) -> AST {
  auto ast = multiplication(it, end);

  while (it != end and it->type == Type::Add) {
    auto token = *it++;
    ast = std::make_unique<Binary>(Binary{ token, std::move(ast), multiplication(it, end) });
  }

  return ast;
}

auto expression(CIT &it, CIT end) -> AST {
  return addition(it, end);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Token> tokens = {
    { Type::Num, "5"},
    { Type::Add, "+"},
    { Type::LParen, "("},
    { Type::Num, "4"},
    { Type::Mul, "*"},
    { Type::Num, "3"},
    { Type::RParen, ")"},
  };

  auto it = tokens.begin();
  auto ast = expression(it, tokens.end());
}
```

Here there is a circular dependency of recursive calls: `addition` depends on `multiplication`, `multiplication` depends on `literal`, and `literal` 'depends on' `addition`.

I'd like to see if there is a way to flatten these calls into a singular iterative call. My first thoughts were to loop through the tokens and do a switch case between the precedence of operators; however, I am unsure where to go come there.

Non-complete attempt:

```
auto parse(const std::vector<Token>& tokens) -> AST {
  AST current;

  enum class Precedent {
    Addition, Multiplication, Literal
  };

  for (const auto& token : tokens) {
    switch (precedent) {
      case Precedent::Addition: {
        ???
      } break;
      case Precedent::Multiplication: {
        ???
      } break;
      case Precedent::Literal: {
        ???
      } break;
    }
  }

  return current;
}
```

I feel that I am missing some kind of stack as a lot of iterative solutions from recursive solutions appear to maintain a manual call-like stack.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Edit: I've reviewed the post referring to the duplicate, though I believe my question is different that the one linked. I am not trying to make a single recursive function into an iterative one, I am trying to make multiple recursive functions into a single iterative function. I hope that explains why I asked this question.

Comment: Regarding downvoting. There are many downvote trolls who would simply downvote, because you are new and have a low rep. Do not take it serious and continue asking. You may read in meta about that. You are writing a parser, which needs a lot of understanding, e.g. the theory about formal languages. You definitely need a stack for parsing a language in a more upper Chomsky hierachy. Somehow complicated. You may see an example in my github repository, where I implemented 2 compilers in one piece of code. And, especially an AST as a vector. Maybe it helps: https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need a stack in order to parse nested expressions. Recursive-descent parsers use the call stack, which is convenient because it frees you from needing to implement a managed stack datatype; the cost is that since you are not managing the stack, you rely on the host-language runtime to detect stack overflow. And the host language you've chosen (C++) doesn't do that.

Predictive (top-down) parsing can easily be implemented with an explicit stack. The stack, which contains grammar symbols, represents unresolved predictions. Initially, it consists of the start symbol and the end-of-input token. (The start symbol is on top.)

The parse algorithm is extremely simple:

- If the top of the stack is a terminal type, then the next token must be a token of that type.

  - If it is, the input token is processed and the stack is popped; if the stack is now empty, the parse is complete.
  - If the input token is not of the expected type, the parse fails.
- If the top of the stack is a non-terminal symbol, an appropriate production for that symbol is selected based on a peek at the next input token. (Or tokens, if your parser requires more than one lookahead.)

  - If there is a possible production, the stack is popped, and the right-hand side of the predicted production is pushed right-to-left onto the stack (so that the first symbol in the right-hand side is on the top of the stack).
  - If no production for the predicted symbol can start with the current lookahead, the parse fails.

A slightly more complicated prediction algorithm must be used if there are empty productions; an empty production is predicted based on its FOLLOW set, not its FIRST set.

---

In practice, you'll want to actually do something with each recognized terminal. That generally requires another stack (or stacks) and roughly corresponds to evaluating a forward Polish (prefix) expression.

Comment: I see. I'll go ahead and explore that. If a solution comes up I'll go ahead and link to to it later.